# Android Studio - Login page not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to make a simple login page that with the correct username and password will go to another activity (Already been created) Also the attempt counter isn't functioning properly. Sorry If this poorly worded, hopefully it makes sense.

```
public class login extends Activity {

private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private Button login;
private TextView loginLocked;
private TextView attemptsLeft;
private TextView numberOfRemainingLoginAttemptsTV;
int numberOfRemainingLoginAttempts = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    setupVariables();
}

public void Login(View view) {
    if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("secret")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome User",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        numberOfRemainingLoginAttempts--;
        attemptsLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        numberOfRemainingLoginAttemptsTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        numberOfRemainingLoginAttemptsTV.setText(Integer.toString(numberOfRemainingLoginAttempts));

        if (numberOfRemainingLoginAttempts == 0) {
            login.setEnabled(false);
            loginLocked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loginLocked.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            loginLocked.setText("Please Try Again Later");
        }
    }
}

private void setupVariables() {
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    loginLocked = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginLocked);
    attemptsLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attemptsLeft);
    numberOfRemainingLoginAttemptsTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberOfRemainingLoginAttemptsTV);
    numberOfRemainingLoginAttemptsTV.setText(Integer.toString(numberOfRemainingLoginAttempts));
}
}
```

Comment: "Is not working" doesn't say anything about what goes wrong with your code. Please improve the description, point out what you're expecting and what happens.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `startActivity()` you have to use it on the context (Not always. Only in certain conditions but I think it is a good practice to declare it on the context). So change `startActivity(i)` to `login.this.startActivity(i);`

Hopefully that should get it running.
Hope it helps!

EDIT: pls post your Layout file as well. AND in your public void login add this

REMEMBER: put it directly in the void and NOT in the `if` statement

```
Log.i("LOGIN DETAILS","Username: "+username.getText().toString()+"Password: "+password.getText().toString());
```

Then post your log cat with the info filter.

If your not so good with the log cat you can instead add this line of code in your public void login NOT in `if` statement

```
Toast.makeText(login.this, "Username: "+ username.getText().toString() + "password: " + password.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Tried that, 'login.this startActivity(i);' got a ';' expected after the .this

Comment: Sorry it's` login.this.startActivity(i);` Autocorrect sorry

Comment: No problem! Nope still does nothing when I enter the correct details and press the button. @KISHORE_ZE

Comment: @DeeMoMo Please check my edited answer and let me know the results you get. That will help us understand where the error is. Thanks

Comment: Using "this" when calling a method is optional, I don't see how it will solve the problem. And why are you asking the OP to print user name and password into the logcat? How should that help?

Comment: @Egor You need to call `this` if you nest your startActivity() in a bunch of statements. Do you not know this? Also I need to know what the result he gets from his edit text is! So I can check if the if statement runs. From the looks of it the if statement is not running. You need to know the cause why! So please stop down voting other answers if you don't know the reason

Comment: @DeeMoMo Any result?